# Undefined string in email output

Tags: php, jquery, email, undefined

This contact form is driving me crazy!! Everything works except some variables I receive in email, but i receive them as "undefined". I'm not getting any errors on screen.
I'm using php and javascript for validating.

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

$to_email = "";
$from_fullname = "";
$from_email = "";
$phone_number = "";
$email_subject = "";
$mois = "";
$jour = "";
$annee = "";
$check_box_values = "";
$rue = "";
$adresse2 = "";
$ville = "";
$province = "";
$varcountry = "";
$codepostal = "";
$varhouse = "";
$email_message = "";
$security_code = "";
$vpb_message_body = "";
$headers = "";

if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && !empty($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == 1)
{
global      $to_email,$from_fullname,$from_email,$mois,$jour,$annee,$check_box_values,$rue,$adresse2,$ville,$province,$varcountry,$codepostal,$varhouse,$phone_number,$email_message,$email_subject,$security_code,$vpb_message_body,$headers;

//Read POST request params into global vars
$to_email          = "myemail@gmail.com"; // Replace this email field with your email address or your company email address
$from_fullname     = trim(strip_tags($_POST['fullname']));
$from_email        = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$phone_number        = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
$email_message     = trim(strip_tags($_POST['message']));
$security_code     = trim(strip_tags($_POST['vpb_captcha_code']));
$mois              = trim(strip_tags($_POST['mois']));
$jour              = trim(strip_tags($_POST['jour']));
$annee             = trim(strip_tags($_POST['annee']));
$check_box_values = utf8_encode("");
if(isset($_POST['time'])){
foreach($_POST['time'] as $value){
$check_box_values .= $value;
$check_box_values .= ', ';
}
}
$rue               = trim(strip_tags($_POST['road']));
$adresse2          = trim(strip_tags($_POST['adresse2']));
$ville             = trim(strip_tags($_POST['ville']));
$province          = trim(strip_tags($_POST['province']));
if(isset($_POST['pays']) )
{
$varcountry = $_POST['pays'];
}
$codepostal        = trim(strip_tags($_POST['postal']));
if(isset($_POST['maison']) )
{

$varhouse = $_POST['maison'];

}

$vpb_message_body = nl2br("Cher Admin,\n
L'utilisateur dont le d&eacute;tail est indiqu&eacute; ci-dessous a envoy&eacute; ce message de ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']." dat&eacute; ".date('d-m-Y').".\n

Nom: ".$from_fullname."\n
Courriel: ".$from_email."\n
Num&eacute;ro T&eacute;l&eacute;phone: ".$phone_number."\n
Date d&rsquo;inspection d&eacute;sir&eacute;e: ".$mois."&nbsp;".$jour."&nbsp;".$annee."\n
Temps pr&eacute;f&eacute;r&eacute; pour &ecirc;tre contact&eacute;: ".$check_box_values."\n
Adresse de la propri&eacute;t&eacute;: ".$rue."&nbsp;".$adresse2."&nbsp;".$ville."&nbsp;".$province."&nbsp;".$varcountry."&nbsp;".$codepostal."\n
Type de propri&eacute;t&eacute;: ".$varhouse."\n
Message: ".$email_message."\n


Merci!\n\n");

//Set up the email headers
$headers      = "From: $from_fullname <$from_email>\r\n";
$headers   .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers   .= "Message-ID: <".time().rand(1,1000)."@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">". "\r\n";   

//More validation for the input fields
if($from_fullname == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre nom complet dans le champ requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif($from_email == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre courriel dans le champ courriel requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $from_email))
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">D&eacute;sol&eacute;, votre courriel n&#39;est pas valide. S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t entrer un courriel valide pour continuer. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif($phone_number == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone dans le champ requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif($mois == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre MOIS dans le champ requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>';
}

elseif($email_message == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre message dans le champ de message requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif($security_code == "")
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t entrez le code de s&eacute;curit&eacute; dans son champ pour nous envoyer votre message. Merci.</div>';
}
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['vpb_captcha_code']))
{
    echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">D&eacute;sol&eacute;, aucune session appropri&eacute;e a &eacute;t&eacute; cr&eacute;&eacute; pour le code de s&eacute;curit&eacute; à suivre. S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t rafra&icirc;chir la page et essayez à nouveau. Merci.</div>';
}
else
{
    if(empty($_SESSION['vpb_captcha_code']) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['vpb_captcha_code'], $_POST['vpb_captcha_code']) != 0)
    {
        //Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively. If you want case sensitive match, update the check above to strcmp()
        echo '<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">D&eacute;sol&eacute;, le code de s&eacute;curit&eacute; que vous avez fournie est incorrecte, s&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t essayer à nouveau. Merci.</div>';
    }
    else
    {
         if(@mail($to_email, $email_subject, $vpb_message_body, $headers))
         {
            //Displays the success message when email message is sent
              echo "<br clear='all'><div align='left' class='vpb_success'>F&eacute;licitations ".$from_fullname.", votre message a &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute; avec succ&egrave;s!<br>Nous vous r&eacute;pondrons d&egrave;s que possible. Merci.</div>";
         } 
         else 
         {
             //Displays an error message when email sending fails
              echo "<br clear='all'><div align='left' class='vpb_info'>D&eacute;sol&eacute;, votre message n&#39;a pas pu être envoy&eacute; pour le moment.<br>S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t essayer de nouveau ou contacter l&#39;administrateur de site Web et signaler ce message d&#39;erreur si le probl&egrave;me persiste. Merci.</div>";
         }
    }
}
}

?>
```

HTML

```
     <div class="contact-form" style="width:65%;">


      <!-- Code Begins Here -->


<h3>S'il vous plaît remplir le formulaire ci-dessous pour nous rejoindre ...</h3>


<span><label>Nom et prénom:</span></label>
<span><input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname"></span>

<span><label>Courriel:</span></label>
<span><input type="text" id="email" name="email"></span>

<span><label>Numéro Téléphone:</span></label>
<span><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value=""></span>

<span><label>Date d&rsquo;inspection désirée</span></label>
<span><ul>
            <li id="li_4" >
        <span style="width:15%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_1" id="mois" name="mois" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text">
            <label for="element_4_1">MM</label>
        </span>
        <span style="width:22%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_2" id="jour" name="jour" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2"  type="text">
            <label for="element_4_2">JJ</label>
        </span>
        <span style="width:18%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_3" id="annee" name="annee" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" type="text">
            <label for="element_4_3">AAAA</label>
        </span>

        <span id="calendar_4">
            <img id="cal_img_4" class="datepicker" src="../web/calendar.gif" alt="Choisir une date.">   
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Calendar.setup({
            inputField   : "element_4_3",
            baseField    : "element_4",
            displayArea  : "calendar_4",
            button       : "cal_img_4",
            ifFormat     : "%B %e, %Y",
            onSelect     : selectDate
            });
        </script>

        </li>
        </ul></span>

<br clear="all">
<span><label>SELECTIONNEZ LES HEURES AUXQUELLES VOUS SOUHAITEZ ÊTRE CONTACTÉ </span></label>
<span style="width:10%; float:left;">
            <input name="time[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Matin" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_1">Matin</label>
</span>
<span style="width:15%; float:left;">
<input ame="time[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Après-Midi" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_2">Après-Midi</label>
</span>

<span style="width:10%; float:left;">
<input name="time[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="Soirée" />
<label class="choice" for="element_8_3">Soirée</label>
</span>

<br clear="all">
<span><label>Adresse de la propriété </label></span>

        <div>
            <input id="element_5_1" name="road" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <span><label>Rue</label></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="element_5_2" name="adresse2" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <span><label>Adresse Ligne 2</label></span>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_5_3" name="ville" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <span><label>Ville</label></span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <input id="element_5_4" name="province" class="element text medium" value="" type="text">
            <span><label>État / Province / Région</label></span>
        </div>

        <div class="left" style="width:30%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_5_5" name="postal" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text">
            <span><label>Code Postal / Zip Code</label></span>
        </div>

        <div class="left" style="width:50%; float:left; margin-left:20px;">
            <span><select class="element select medium" id="element_5_6" name="pays" style="height:38px;"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="Canada" >Canada</option>
            <option value="United States" >États-Unis</option>
        </select></span>
        <span><label>Pays</label></span>
    </div> 

<br clear="all">
<span><label>Type de Propriété </label></span>
<span><select class="element select medium" id="element_9" name="maison"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Bungalow" >Bungalow</option>
        <option value="Condo" >Condo</option>
        <option value="Duplex" >Duplex</option>
        <option value="Triplex" >Triplex</option>
        <option value="Autre" >Autre</option>

     </select></span>

<span><label>Message</label></span>
<span><textarea id="message" name="message" class="vpb_input_fields"></textarea><br clear="all"><br clear="all">

<div class="vpb_captcha_wrapper"><img src="vasplusCaptcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ></div><br clear="all">
<span>Vous ne pouvez pas lire le code de sécurité ci-dessus? <a class="ccc" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="vpb_refresh_aptcha();">Actualiser</a></span>
<span><label>Code de sécurité</label></span>
<span><input type="text" id="vpb_captcha_code" name="vpb_captcha_code" style="border-bottom: solid 2px #cbcbcb;" class="vpb_input_fields"></span><br clear="all">

<span class="vpb_general_button" onclick="vpb_submit_form();" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Envoyer</span>
</div>
<br clear="all">
<div id="response_brought"></div><!-- This will display the response from the server -->

</div>

</center>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT ( i think the problem lies here but i don't know what it is)

```
//This function refreshes the security or captcha code when you click on the refresh link at the form
function vpb_refresh_aptcha()
{
    return document.getElementById("vpb_captcha_code").value="",document.getElementById("vpb_captcha_code").focus(),document.images['captchaimg'].src = document.images['captchaimg'].src.substring(0,document.images['captchaimg'].src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
}



//This is the JS function that sends the mail - It is called when you click on the submit button which is in the form
function vpb_submit_form()
{
    //Variable declaration and assignment
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var mois = $("#mois").val();
    var jour = $("#jour").val(); 
    var annee = $("#annee").val(); 
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var vpb_captcha_code = $("#vpb_captcha_code").val();

    if( fullname == "" ) //Validation against empty field for fullname
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre nom complet dans le champ requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>');
        $("#fullname").focus();
    }
    else if( email == "" ) //Validation against empty field for email address
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre courriel dans le champ courriel requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>');
        $("#email").focus();
    }
    else if(reg.test(email) == false) //Validation for working email address
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">D&eacute;sol&eacute;, votre courriel n&#39;est pas valide. S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t entrer un courriel valide pour continuer. Merci.</div>');
        $("#email").focus();
    }
    else if( phone == "" ) //Validation against empty field for telephone number
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone dans le champ requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>');
        $("#phone").focus();
    }
    else if( subject == "" ) //Validation against empty field for email subject
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous plaît entrez l&#39;objet de votre message dans le champ requis de procéder. Merci.</div>');
        $("#subject").focus();
    }
    else if( mois == "" ) //Validation against empty field for month
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous plaît entrez l&#39;objet de votre mois dans le champ requis de procéder. Merci.</div>');
        $("#mois").focus();
    }
    else if( message == "" ) //Validation against empty field for email message
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t, entrez votre message dans le champ de message requis de proc&eacute;der. Merci.</div>');
        $("#message").focus();
    }
    else if( vpb_captcha_code == "" ) //Validation against empty field for security captcha code
    {
        $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div class="vpb_info" align="left">S&#39;il vous pla&icirc;t entrez le code de s&eacute;curit&eacute; dans son champ pour nous envoyer votre message. Merci.</div>');
        $("#vpb_captcha_code").focus();
    }
    else
    {
        var dataString = 'fullname=' + fullname + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&mois=' + mois + '&jour=' + jour + '&annee=' + annee + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message + '&vpb_captcha_code=' + vpb_captcha_code + '&submitted=1';
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "vpb_contact_form.php",  
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                //Show loading image
                $("#response_brought").html('<br clear="all"><div align="left" style=" padding-top:6px; margin-left:100px; margin-top:15px;"><font style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:black;">S&#39;il vous plaît attendre</font> <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="chargement en cours...." align="absmiddle" title="chargement en cours...."/></div>');

            },  
            success: function(response)
            {
                //Check to see if the message is sent or not
                var response_brought = response.indexOf('félicitations');
                if( response_brought != -1 )
                {
                    //Clear all form fields on success
                    $("#fullname").val('');
                    $("#email").val('');
                    $("#phone").val('');
                    $("#subject").val('');
                    $("#mois").val('');
                    $("#jour").val(''); 
                    $("#annee").val('');
                    $("#message").val('');
                    $("#vpb_captcha_code").val('');

                    //Display success message if the message is sent
                    $("#response_brought").html(response);

                    //Remove the success message also after a while of displaying the message to the user
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#response_brought").html('');
                    },10000);
                }  
                else  
                {
                    //Display error message is the message is not sent
                     $("#response_brought").html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EMAIL OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS:

Cher Admin,

L'utilisateur dont le détail est indiqué ci-dessous a envoyé ce message de 10.1.2.31 daté 25-02-2014.

Nom: Crystal

Courriel: TEST@gmail.com

Numéro Téléphone: 555-555-5555

Date d’inspection désirée: undefined undefined undefined

Temps préféré pour être contacté:

Adresse de la propriété:

Type de propriété:

Message: dknlsnf

Merci!

undefined is $mois $jour $annee

Any ideas? Thanks people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salut!

In your variable:

```
var dataString = 'fullname=' + fullname + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&mois=' + mois + '&jour=' + jour + '&annee=' + annee + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message + '&vpb_captcha_code=' + vpb_captcha_code + '&submitted=1';
```

You never call

```
 id="element_4_1"
 id="element_4_2"
 id="element_4_3"
```

Which have **TWO IDS (You should only use one)** in: "inspection désirée"

```
<span><label>Date d&rsquo;inspection désirée</span></label>
<span><ul>
            <li id="li_4" >
        <span style="width:15%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_1" id="mois" name="mois" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text">
            <label for="element_4_1">MM</label>
        </span>
        <span style="width:22%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_2" id="jour" name="jour" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2"  type="text">
            <label for="element_4_2">JJ</label>
        </span>
        <span style="width:18%; float:left;">
            <input id="element_4_3" id="annee" name="annee" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" type="text">
            <label for="element_4_3">AAAA</label>
        </span>
```

Bonne chance!

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Ça marche bien maintenant!

Answer (score 2):

```
<span style="width:15%; float:left;">
        <input id="element_4_1" id="mois" name="mois" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text">
        <label for="element_4_1">MM</label>
    </span>
    <span style="width:22%; float:left;">
        <input id="element_4_2" id="jour" name="jour" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2"  type="text">
        <label for="element_4_2">JJ</label>
    </span>
    <span style="width:18%; float:left;">
        <input id="element_4_3" id="annee" name="annee" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" type="text">
        <label for="element_4_3">AAAA</label>
    </span>
```

The input elements have double id="" attributes. Will probably work if you fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You guys have eagle eyes! Works great now and i can finally relax and keep going. :)

Answer (score -1):

if your using jQuery and AJAX go for the normal route of posting data just use http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ this should then mean your code is alot smaller and you not moving data from the form to a query string to send to your server it will do it all for you.

So you just have a standard HTML form
with the action setup method though GET or POST witch ever you want and then you can just call $("#formID").ajaxSubmit();

And your server can be a standard form post system